# What is this lightbulb and how do I change it?

Tags: ceiling, lamp, light-bulb

The lightbulb pictured below is in a ceiling lamp fixture in the United States and is probably original to the house, meaning approximately 1985 vintage.

There is no lettering or labeling I can see on the bulb, just the faint bossing on the lamp itself ("Nadair"?) to identify it.

The glass is fairly small, no more than a few inches long, much less than an inch wide.  There is no obvious direction to tug or twist it that releases it, although I've been reluctant to pull hard for fear of breaking it in my hand.  (On that note, this fixture is old and it took quite a bit of brute force to pry the one extendable claw out to release the cover.)

The white plastic pieces seem to be part of the fixture itself.

What is this thing, and what is the trick to removing it?

It has now been removed, and is the subject of the third image and the new question, "Did I break this thing?"  But I can get it to a hardware store, now, which is more than half the battle.

[image: Width]
[image: Length]
[image: Removed]

Comment: Related question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63208/how-do-i-remove-a-double-ended-t3-r7s-bulb-that-isnt-spring-loaded

Comment: Totally off topic, but I keep thinking of *"how many X does it take to change a light bulb"* jokes :)

Comment: With a Kleenex otherwise the oils from your hands degrade the bulb.

Comment: You would find one of those bulbs in any "dorm-room special" floor-standing torchiere lamp sold in the 1990s, and in fact the circular hole in the bracket located _above_ the bulb (along with the fact that it's clearly mounted off-center from the ceiling box, and was never meant to be used with one) makes me think this fixture was repurposed from one of those. (Edit: Maybe not off-center. That weird screw/protrusion at the very top of the first photo threw me off. ...Still ghetto-looking, tho. Replace the fixture!)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a double-ended halogen lamp. Looks a lot like a T3 size but I'm having trouble locating a picture of one so short in length as yours appears.

The ceramic blocks at the ends of the lamp conceal a spring loaded terminal. Push the lamp sideways (along its axis) toward one of the blocks, then lift the opposite end of the lamp out of the holder.

Sometimes the fixture terminal and the lamp terminal can stick together. You could try twisting the lamp just a little or inserting some tool into the end block to help separate them.

One might argue this is all a bit academic.. replace the entire fixture with a quality fluorescent or LED model!

Comment: Halogen bulbs get really hot.  Make sure it is cool before following @Greg Hill's clear advice.

Comment: do not touch the new one with bare hands ... skin oils will kill it

Comment: That worked, although I'm not sure if I broke it.  Hopefully I'll have it identified tomorrow, at a hardware store if need be.  And while I'm tempted to replace the fixture, that's not in my time budget right now.

Comment: If you can spare half an hour I would still consider replacing it with a LED fixture, the electricity saved alone will already make it worthwhile.

Comment: Shopping is off topic here, but just to address the budget comment. I searched Amazon for ceiling light fixtures, and a UL listed LED fixture (or one for traditional screw in lamps, which can use LED “bulbs”) aren’t much more than I think you’d pay for that halogen bulb.

Comment: @Reader If it's actually a standard size like the 78 mm R7S, you can just go buy a compatible LED bulb, no need to replace the whole fixture.

Comment: Yes, 100% go LED!  Incandescent fixtures, especially halogens, in addition to just being wasteful, make SO much heat.  I can't count the number of crufty old octo-boxes I've seen where the wires have been so heat-scorched by halogen or incandescent bulbs that the insulation just shatters like glass - it makes a real mess to sort out if you ever want to change the fixture.  Best to nip that problem in the bud and use a cool lamp like an LED instead.

Comment: @TimB I can pick up one of these halogens for AU$2.25. Pretty sure you'd be hard pressed to find a fixture and LED lamp for anything close to that price :)

Comment: @Corey - And I can't imagine that you would be able to find a CF or LED replacement that could come anywhere NEAR the brightness of a halogen bulb...

Comment: You can get fairly bright LED ceiling lights tbh. I have a pair of 12 watts in my living room that come in handy when in need of floodlights.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add a bit of terminology info from the web to Greg's excellent answer:

> T type halogen bulbs feature the letter “T” to indicate their tubular shape, followed by a number which specifies the tube's diameter.in eighths of an inch. For instance, a T3 bulb is a tubular halogen bulb which has a diameter measuring 3/8ths of an inch.

> An R7S is a double ended, recessed single contact (RSC) linear halogen lamp measuring either 118 mm or 78 mm. Some less common lengths are 189 mm, 254 mm and 331 mm. These lamps have a T3 shape on an RSC/R7S base. These can also be known as J type and T type lamps. (From an Amazon QA comment)

Your bulb looks like it's probably 78mm long. BTW, yes, the photo shows a broken bulb.

Also, it's VERY important to make sure the wattage of the bulb is lower than the safe limit for the fixture -- otherwise a fire can result, as these bulbs get VERY hot.

Comment: I also thought it's an R7S,but OP's photo shows it to be a little under 3 inches long. That's nowhere near 118 mm, actually not even 78 mm. If it was any of these common sizes,OP could easily buy a drop-in replacement LED bulb.

Comment: @TooTea Thanks for catching my mistake, I meant 78mm. OP's photo shows the ceramic ends broken off and it looks to me that with them in place it would be slightly over 3 inches. I could be wrong.

Comment: If the ceramic ends broke off when removing the bulb, it's possible that the fixture was also damaged in the process.  I'd recommend a careful inspection of this before replacing the bulb.  If the fixture is at all damaged, that's another point in favor of replacing it with a fluorescent/LED fixture.

Answer (score 5):

Last time I bought halogen bulbs like that, 1000bulbs dot com.

If that's a 100W bulb (1000bulbs carries 100W, 150W, 250W), it's $2 (for the bulb; considerably more for the power to run it, if it sees significant use; an enormous amount more if you have a fire):

[Plusrite 3350 - 100 Watt - T3](https://www.1000bulbs.com/product/5107/Q-J10006.html)

Handle the new bulb *only* with a clean tissue or equivalent, to avoid skin oils damaging the bulb.

I would not worry excessively about the ceramic ends breaking off of the old bulb, though do inspect the fixture prongs for corrosion and wipe them clean.  The bulb obviously gets *extremely* hot during operation, but transfers a limited amount of heat to the socket.

Inspect the fixture prongs with the breaker off; no guarantee that mis-wiring doesn't have 120V on one end.

I second the "put in an LED fixture if you can" comments.  You will save money and it will be safer, unless you need the heat for some reason.

Comment: +1 for the heat point - sometimes it is useful.